# Not getting complete string response from retrofit in android

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I am trying to execute the following query in my PHP file.

> show create table test.account;

When I echo the response I am only getting the first word of the query i.e. CREATE.
I surrounded the whole query by single quotes but when I echo the response I only get the response from first single quote to next single quote (next single quote is used for some default string), not the whole query.

Following is my API interface code -

```
@GET("createQueries.php/")
Call<String> loadCreateQueries(@Query("tableName") String tableName);
```

My PHP code -

```
 <?php

    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if ( !$con){
        echo "Database Connection Error";
    }

    // selecting database
    $select = mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE);
    if ( !$select){
        echo "Database Selection Error";
    }

    $tableName = $_GET["tableName"];


    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW CREATE TABLE test.".$tableName);

    if ($result != false) {
        $create_query = "'{";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $fields = array_values($row);
            $create_query = $create_query.$fields[1];
        }
        $create_query = $create_query."}'";
        echo $create_query;
    } else {
        echo "Table not in server";
    }

?>
```

Response

```
{CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `interestRate` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalInterestReceived` float DEFAULT
```

Client code -

```
  public void createTable() {
    if (tableNames.length > tableIndex) {
        NetworkUtil.getAPI(getApplicationContext()).loadCreateQueries(tableNames[tableIndex]).enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String query = response.body().getAsString();
                    Log.d("Create Query - ", query);

                } else System.out.println(response.errorBody());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing `String` with `JsonElement`, here `Call<String> loadCreateQueries`

Comment: I getting the same response @KarandeepAtwal

Comment: what is your full android client code? including some `Log.d` debug calls?

Comment: I had updated my code @pskink

Comment: use [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) for more verbose debug stuff, what does `logcat` show now?

Comment: It was not a log issue.

Comment: of course it is not `"a log issue"` but using the logging stuff correctly you will save a lot of your time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best approach but I replace the single quotes by %27 and before echo, I had surrounded it by single quotes.

Here is updated code -

```
if ($result != false) {
    $create_query = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fields = array_values($row);
        $create_query = $create_query.$fields[1];
    }
    //$create_query = $create_query."";

    $create_query = str_replace('\'', '%27', $create_query);
    echo "'".$create_query."'";
} else {
    echo "Table not in server";
}
```